# inexplicable space inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a divider for my page, usign three divs with different colors to form a  single line with a height of 2px. I am creating a div with 3 subdivs, each with a height of 2 px.The parent div is inexplicably taking a space of 18px, I thought the parent div should only occupy the space of his children.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <div class="separator">
        <span class="third t1"></span><!--
        --><div class="third t2"></div><!--
        --><div class="third t3"></div>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
.separator {
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;        
}   

.third {
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.t1 {
    background-color: #ff7474;  
}

.t2 {
    background-color: #f1f58d;  
}

.t3 {
    background-color: #72baf1;  
}
```

Here is the codepen.io link for my code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjdnx

Comment: example fiddle? also, depending on `display` and `position`, a div will usually take up 100% width that is available to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that because you are using inline block the separator div is using the font size to determine it's height and the line-height of the child elements.

First you need to comment out all of the white space (as `display:inline-block` will treat the elements like words in a sentence so white spaces will show up between them):

```
<div class="separator"><!--
    --><span class="third t1"></span><!--
    --><div class="third t2"></div><!--
    --><div class="third t3"></div><!--
--></div>
```

then you need to add the following style to your separator div:

```
.separator {
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;    
    font-size:2px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7h3M5/1/)

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have thought about font size. You sir are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCK4X/)

Just add `float:left;` to `.third` class. It's one way to get rid of the space that `display:inline-block` creates. I've also removed `margin-top:-10px` (else you cannot see the elements)

**Before**

```
.third {
   height: 2px;
   margin-top: -10px;
   width: 33.33%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

**After**

```
.third {
   float:left;
   height: 2px;
   width: 33.33%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

***Remeber*** : Floating elements needs a parent with `overflow:hidden` or an element with `clear:both` after them.

Comment: My supervisor here at the internship I'm taking at this firm strongly forbids me to use floats, he says I should never use these.

Comment: @Radu don't let yourself be fooled by your supervisor. Floats have their use cases, if you know how to use them. Here's a good article regarding the topic: http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101

Comment: I quote Yoshi. Floats are not evil. Good article by the way